# Retrieving user's groups from Keycloak via pac4j library

Tags: java, keycloak, openid-connect, pac4j

I'm protecting a JavaEE running on Tomcat with the library `javaee-pac4j` with an OpenID Connect flow (with library `pac4j-oidc`) that is managed by a Keycloak istance.

After a successful login in Keycloak for a protected resource, I obtain the `UserProfile` from the `WebContext` and `SessionStore` inherited by the default pac4j logics. I'm able to obtain various like roles, permissions, attributes, etc.. but I see no clear way to retrieve the groups where the user is in inside Keycloak.

Is there any method of the `pac4j-oidc` library that returns me said group list, or should I create a custom mapper in the Keycloak client configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `KeycloakOidcClient` and with this client, comes the `KeycloakRolesAuthorizationGenerator`: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/5.7.x/pac4j-oidc/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oidc/authorization/generator/KeycloakRolesAuthorizationGenerator.java which puts the Keycloak roles information as the roles of the pac4j authenticated user profile.

Any other attribute can be retrieved via `getAttribute` method of the `UserProfile`.

Comment: I am already using a `KeycloakOidcClient` configured with a callback URL on which a Filter is in place.

In this Filter I'm retrieving the `UserProfile` as previously stated. but I can already access the roles from this class without the need of `KeycloakRolesAuthorizationGenerator`. I'm trying to access the user's **groups**, not roles, that are missing from your suggested class as well.

Comment: All data from Keycloak are at least available via the pac4j user attributes. There must be an attribute with your Keycloak groups or the info is not returned by Keycloak (configuration issue).